# Migrate data between WSL distributions

Tags: upgrade, windows-subsystem-for-linux, data-migration

```
>wsl -l
Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
Ubuntu-18.04 (Default)
Ubuntu
```

I made the mistake of setting up everything in the `Ubuntu-18.04` version, which is locked to that specific version and doesn't allow dist upgrades (Please prove me wrong). This includes shell customizations, symlinks etc.

I would however like to upgrade Ubuntu every once in a while. What I do not want to do is manually find all the configuration files and copy them to the new distribution.

The `Ubuntu` distribution is the one from the Windows store; fresh clean with no modifications.

*How do I get my data from the old distribution into the fresh `Ubuntu` store distribution? Or is there a way to upgrade the locked `Ubuntu-18.04` distribution (also from the Windows store)?*

I know of `wsl --export` and `wsl --import`, but as far as I can tell these keep the distribution (with in this case the lack of upgrades) and just place a copy of that distribution into another folder. Which does not solve the dist upgrade problem.

Comment: Installing an Ubuntu distribution from Microsoft Store installs a WSL distribution of the same name on your Windows. The MS Store package "Ubuntu" just installs the current LTS version of Ubuntu (20.04 at the moment) but the result should be the same as installing the explicitly named version. Just the name will be different. --- Upgrades of the installed WSL distribution are managed from inside of them using do-release-upgrade. After a WSL distribution is installed MS Store does not modify (upgrade) or prevent modifying (upgrading) it.

Comment: @pabouk this was a few months ago, but I remember trying everything I could to upgrade my existing Installation. To the point where I went mad and pasted answers from AskUbuntu, without any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the free, legacy version of [Aptik](https://github.com/teejee2008/aptik) (I couldn't get the GTK version to launch). Even though it's no longer maintained, it's still working perfectly well, and only took me a single command to export everything and another single command to import everything again.